# Dispose/reset providers after logging out

Tags: flutter

How can I dispose or reset all my providers?
If user logged out I need to reset all providers, so all provider flows are triggered again for new logged-in user.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is the job of your `Provider` to handle the disposal: It should close streams when the provider widget is removed from the tree.

What you need to do is to place your Providers above only "logged-in user" widget tree, so that when user is logged out and placed above lets say to login route your providers will be disposed with removed widgets automatically.

The following example instantiates a `Model` once, and disposes it when
`Provider` is removed from the tree.

```dart
 class Model {
   void dispose() {}
 }

 class Stateless extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Provider<Model>(
       create: (context) =>  Model(),
       dispose: (context, value) => value.dispose(),
       child: ...,
     );
   }
 }
```

It is worth noting, that `Provider.value` exposes an existing value without disposing it.

Comment: So every Provider needs it own dispose method? What to write in it? I just want to trigger constructor again.. I think I need to refactor, because now basically all my providers are top-level.